# Fade in and out background image on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, fade

i've got some script that lets me hover over a descendant and add a class to a ancestor, was wondering what the code would be to add a fadein to the element. Hovering li.icon_bg1 adds the class bg_change to .parallax_bg. and in my css bg_change has a background-image that i change

```
$('.parallax_bg .row .col-md-6 .activity .top_row li.icon_bg1').hover(function(){
    $(this).parents(".parallax_bg").addClass('bg_change');
}, function() {
    $(this).parents(".parallax_bg").removeClass('bg_change');
})
```

Comment: What is your problem with this code ?

Comment: If you want to know how to fade in in JQuery it's `$(this).fadeIn(/*Time in milliseconds*/ 1000);`

Comment: nothing wrong with the code, just want to add into it a fadein

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xaLn1z32/

here is the fiddle. basically what i want to happen is fade in the other image and fade out as it goes in and out of hover instead of the hard cut that it does in and out of hover

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jQuery's built in fadeIn() function, or you can simply add a fade in transition on the class you are adding/removing.

```
.parallax_bg {
  transition: opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.parallax_bg.bg_change {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your question. After reading your response, all you need to add is `transition: background-image 0.5s;` to your .parallax_bg class.

```
.parallax_bg {
  transition: background-image 0.5s;
  background-image: url(corgi-img.jpg);
}
```

Comment: thanks but not exactly what i was looking for 

https://jsfiddle.net/xaLn1z32/

here is the fiddle. basically what i want to happen is fade in the other image and fade out as it goes in and out of hover instead of the hard cut that it does in and out of hover

Comment: Fiddle helps more than anything, next time you should start with that. My edited response should be exactly what you need.